# Как правильно расположить блоки с отступами flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: пример]

Как правильно сделать такую сетку на flex?
Если задать родителю `justify-content: space-between;` то нижняя строка будет располагаться с большими отступами (левый и правый блоки будут по разные стороны). Если убрать justify-content и сделать отступы через `margin-right` то самый правый блок с каждой строке будет не у края. Как решить эту проблему?

Код https://jsfiddle.net/tj0o72gr/6/

```
<div class="list">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>

.list {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.item {
  width: 23%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример вашего кода по вопросу

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tj0o72gr/6/

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить

```
.list::after {
  content: '';
  width: calc(23% + 165px);
}
```

Число пикселов найдено методом подбора.

Answer (score 1):

> Как правильно сделать такую сетку на flex?

С помощь только CSS - никак, в случае, если мы строим такую сетку, как это изображено на картинке в вашем вопросе или по приведенному вами примеру по ссылке на jsfiddle. Как видно из вопроса, используется два варианта распределения элементов `.item` внутри их общего контейнера `.list`.

1. Построение `justify` (как первая строка элементов на картинке)
2. Построение `inline` (как вторая строка элементов на картинке)

Поэтому мы можем выбрать только один из двух вариантов. Совместить оба варианта, не нарушая `HTML` верстку, технически невозможно. Однако, если вам известно общее количество элементов и их ширина, то вы можете (если это не будет противоречить вашей концепции) предварительно в `HTML` коде разделить все элементы на два контейнера. В первом контейнере распределить элементы по `justify` - выровнять их по левому и правому краю, а во втором `inline` - только по левому краю.

---

Если же у вас такой возможности нет, то предлагаю следующий вариант - `JavaScript`. С помощью вычислений мы получаем количество элементов, которые переносятся на следующую строку и не заполняют ее полностью, оставляя между собой большое расстояние, тем самым нарушают задуманную нами схему распределения элементов. Эти элементы мы заключаем в отдельный контейнер и пишем для него отдельный стиль. По сути это то же самое, что если бы мы в `HTML` коде предварительно распределили все элементы в два разных контейнера. Вариант с помощью `JavaScript` хорош тем, что он сам за вас сделает эту работу. И какое бы количество элементов вы не добавляли в общий контейнер, элементы будут выстраиваться именно в таком порядке, как мы изначально и планировали. Вот пример такого решения<sup>*</sup>:

```js
//Всего элементов
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item').length;
console.log('Всего элементов:', elements);

//Элементов в одной строке
const spl = 100 / 25
const split = parseInt(((spl + "").split("."))[0], 10);
console.log('Элементов в одной строке:', split);

//Полностью заполненных строк элементами
const lines = parseInt(((elements * 25 / 100 + "").split("."))[0], 10);
console.log('Полностью заполненных строк элементами:', lines);

//Элементов во всех полностью заполненных строках
const elems_lines = split * lines
console.log('Элементов во всех полностью заполненных строках:', elems_lines);

//Элементов в остатке
const els = Math.floor(elements - elems_lines)
console.log('Элементов в остатке:', els);

//Элементы, которые в остатке, оборачиваем в отдельный контейнер
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const item = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('els');
list.append(div);
div.append(...item.slice(elems_lines, elements));
```

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 23%;
  height: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.els {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.els .item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 2.66%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

**это решение будет работать правильно, если ширину элементов мы будем указывать в процентах. Если же будут использоваться другие величины, то это решение необходимо будет немного изменить. В вашем вопросе указаны проценты.*